# Deal with excessive number of zeros

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, zero

```
ipdb> np.count_nonzero(test==0) / len(ytrue) * 100                                                                                          
76.44815766923736
```

I have a datafile counting `24000` prices where I use them for a time series forecasting problem. Instead of trying predicting the price, I tried to predict log-return, i.e. `log(P_t/P_P{t-1})`. I have applied the log-return over the prices as well as all the features. The prediction are not bad, but the trend tend to predict zero. As you can see above, `~76%` of the data are zeros.

Now the idea is probably to "look up for a zero-inflated estimator : first predict whether it's gonna be a zero; if not, predict the value".

In details, what is the perfect way to deal with excessive number of zeros? How zero-inflated estimator can help me with that? Be aware originally I am not probabilist.

**P.S.** I am working trying to predict the log-return where the units are "seconds" for High-Frequency Trading study. Be aware that it is a regression problem (not a classification problem).

**Update**

[image]

That picture is probably the best prediction I have on the log-return, i.e `log(P_t/P_{t-1})`. Although it is not bad, the remaining predictions tend to predict zero. As you can see in the above question, there is too many zeros. I have probably the same problem inside the features as I take the log-return on the features as well, i.e. if `F` is a particular feature, then I apply `log(F_t/F_{t-1})`.

Here is a one day data, [log_return_with_features.pkl](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Mk5peBhHlluludUXynAQCW8NAQllbNpA/view?usp=sharing), with shape `(23369, 30, 161)`. Sorry, but I cannot tell what are the features. As I apply log(F_t/F_{t-1}) on all the features and on the target (i.e. the price), then be aware I added 1e-8 to all the features before applying the log-return operation to avoid division by 0.

Comment: are you familiar with the term sparse-matrix? you may want to look at some things associated with that. like COO or CSR format

Comment: @MattR I do not see how sparse matrix concept would be of use here. I always considered it an implementation issue (to save space and possibly computation; never seen 75%-ish zeros as sparse enough to bother, but my experience is limited), while OP seems to be dealing with a data modelling problem. What exactly did you have in mind?

Comment: @dedObed, great points. TBH - I'm confused as to what the OP actually needs. It's why I left my comment vague, "perhaps my comment will help his/her google searching" was the reasoning behind my comment.

Comment: @MattR I thought there was no vague point. Can you tell me more about your confusion? I am looking for a way to deal with the excess zeros. Suppose at a time T fixe, where I have a zero. I am looking for a way to deal with that particular zero according to a certain measure. I might want to remove that zero and the related features without affecting the data structure.

Comment: Would be nice if gave us the shape of your data together with description of the axes, e.g. input : [3 x 10000 x 5] -- [three time series (three currency pairs), 10k samples, 5 features each], output [3 x 10000] -- for every timestep, I want a single number for every currency pair -- the log increase.

Comment: Ok, let me a couple of minutes to update the question.

Comment: @user1050421, what do you mean by `I am looking for a way to deal with that particular zero according to a certain measure.` would converting it to `NaN` be plausible?

Comment: I updated the question. Let me know if I need to modify or add information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so judging from your plot: it's the nature of the data, the price doesn't really change that often.

Try subsampling your original data a bit (perhaps by a factor of 5, just look at the data), so that you generally see a price movement with every time-tick. This should make any modeling much **MUCH** easier.

For the subsampling: I suggest you do simple regular downsampling in time domain. So if you have price data with a second resolution (i.e. one price tag every second), then simply take every fifth datapoint. Then proceed as you usually do, specifically, compute the log-increase in the price from this subsampled data. Remember that whatever you do, it must be reproducible during the test time.

If that is not an option for you for whatever reasons, have a look at something that can handle multiple time scales, e.g. [WaveNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.03499) or [Clockwork RNN](https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.3511).

Comment: I've updated the answer. In short: start as simple as possible. The paper you linked is not really applicable here, it's about dropping whole training examples -- which in your case, would be the whole timeseries.

Comment: I will wait a bit for other answers, but yours is quite interesting!